# stop on alertnotify

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork, alert-system

```
  -alertnotify=<cmd>
       Execute command when a relevant alert is received or we see a really
       long fork (%s in cmd is replaced by message)
```

How to stop Bitcoin Core on a really long fork?
`-alertnotify=stop`?
`-alertnotify="bitcoin-cli stop"`? (assume valid bitcoin-cli can be found in $PATH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bitcoin-cli stop`. All these *notify interfaces accept some cmd as argument.